# How to solve position problem in adapter? Using firebase as the backend

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview, adapter

I'm creating an app with firebase as a backend. I'm using same adapter for different activity, now it is working good but positions were mismatched for example: The output of position 0 shows in position 1 and for position 1 shows in position 2 and so on.. How to solve this problem, The problem with the positions of the output.

```
 Adapter:
    public class FrontlistAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Gamedata, FrontlistAdapter.ViewHolder> {
        private static final String TAG = "GameAdapter";
        Context mContext;
    int positions;
    public FrontlistAdapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Gamedata> options, Context context) {
            super(options);
            mContext = context;
        }
     @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Gamedata model) {
            holder.name.setText(model.getName());
            holder.address.setText(model.getAddress());
            //Picasso.get().load(model.getFrontcover()).into(holder.Frontcover);
            Glide.with(mContext).load(model.getFrontcover()).into(holder.Frontcover);
            positions = position; //<-- here I'm having positions but output shows different for each positions
           
        }
    
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            View v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.gamerow,parent,false);
            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
            return viewHolder;
        }
    
    
        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    
                ImageView Frontcover;
                TextView name;
                TextView address;
            View v;
            public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
    
                Frontcover = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.frontcover);
                name = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.frontname);
                address=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.frontaddress);
                v = itemView;
                itemView.setClickable(true);
                itemView.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
            }
    
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String className = mContext.getClass().getSimpleName();
                Intent intent = null;
                switch (className) {
                    case "GameActivity":
                        intent =  new Intent(mContext, Center_details.class);
                        intent.putExtra("User", getRef(positions).getKey());
                        break;
                    case "KidsActivity":
                        intent = new Intent(mContext,AllCenterDetails.class);
                        intent.putExtra("Kids",getRef(positions).getKey());
                        break;
                }
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Does it happening when you scroll, or it is mismatched from the start?

Comment: It is happening in both cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first what you have to do is create the interface like this

```
  public interface ClickListner {
   void onClick(View view, int position);
  }
```

then in your activity create object of the interface like this and pass to the adapter along with your other data

```
         ClickListner listener = ClickListner();
         FrontlistAdapter customAdapter = new 
         FrontlistAdapter(AcceptedOrdersActivity.this,listener);
         riderView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

copy this outside onCreate and intent in this

```
        private ClickListner ClickListner() {
        ClickListner listener = new ClickListner() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view, int position) {


            int tag = (int) view.getTag();

            if(tag == 0)
            {
                //Intent here
            }

        }
    };

    return listener;
}
```

now your adapter should be this one

```
      public class FrontlistAdapter extends 
      RecyclerView.Adapter<FrontlistAdapter .DataObjectHolder>{

ClickListner listenr;
Context context;

public FrontlistAdapter (Context context,ClickListner listenr) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listenr = listenr;
}

public static class DataObjectHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


    Context context;

    public DataObjectHolder(View itemView,ClickListner listenr) {
        super(itemView);

        this.listenr = listenr;
         Frontcover = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.frontcover);
        name = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.frontname);
        address=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.frontaddress);
        v = itemView;
       
        setOnClickListeners();
    }


    private void setOnClickListeners() {
    `v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            v.setTag(0);
            listenr.onClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    });
    }

}

@NonNull
@Override
public FrontlistAdapter.DataObjectHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, 
int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.cell_orderdetail_list, parent, false);
    FrontlistAdapter.DataObjectHolder dataObjectHolder = new 
FrontlistAdapter.DataObjectHolder(view,listenr);

    return dataObjectHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FrontlistAdapter.DataObjectHolder holder, int 
position) {

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return options.size;
}
```

}

Comment: Now I got your point but why you are using public interface ClickListenr {

    void onClick(View view, int position);
} this code in last line of the adapter?  it shows like it is never used

Comment: sorry that was not a mistake

Comment: Thanks for the one but Now I got another error  Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child() but at first I didn't get that one but now it is showing like this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66119047/cant-pass-null-for-argument-pathstring-in-child-this-the-error-im-getting/66119129#66119129

Answer (score 0):

```
positions = position;
```

This is your problem.  You're setting one global position for everything in the adapter.

Everywhere you are currently using `position`, you should instead be calling [`getBindingAdapterPosition()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder#getBindingAdapterPosition()) on the `ViewHolder`.

Comment: how to use getbindingapdapterposition() in the Viewholder? I used switch case, Should I use this method instead of positions?