# Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()? This the error I'm getting when retrieving data from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm creating an app with firebase as a backend, First I got output but after few changes I did for intent then it shows like this, Can anyone help me to solve this error. I used if to check whether I'm getting data or not and It goes through that if condition still it shows null.

Activity 1:

```
   public class centerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        RecyclerView recyclerView;
        ArrayList<data> mArrayList;
        FrontlistAdapter mAdapter;
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<data> options;
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference().child("Data").child(" Center");
        ClickListner listener = ClickListner();
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_common_template);
    
        //     mArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            TextView title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);
            title.setText("Center");
    
            options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<data>()
                    .setQuery(myRef, data.class)
                   .build();
    
           recyclerView =(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.centerrecycler);
          recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
           mAdapter = new FrontlistAdapter(options,centerActivity.this,listener);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
           recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    
    
        }
    
    
        @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
               mAdapter.startListening();
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
           mAdapter.stopListening();
        }
    
        private ClickListner ClickListner() {
            ClickListner listener = new ClickListner() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view, int position) {
    
    
                    int tag = (int) view.getTag();
    
                    if(tag == 0)
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(centerActivity.this, Center_details.class);
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,position);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
    
                }
            };
    
            return listener;
        }
    }
```

Activity 2:

```
  public class Center_details extends AppCompatActivity {
            private static final String TAG = "Center_Details";
         TextView Name, Address, Timing, About;
        String UsersId;
         @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_center_details);
           
                Name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
                Address = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.address);
                Timing = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timing);
                About = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.About);
    ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Data").child(" Center");

        if (getIntent().hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: Checking for input");
            UsersId  = getIntent().getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
            if ((!TextUtils.isEmpty(UsersId))){
            ref.child(UsersId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot.hasChildren()) {
                                String name = snapshot.child("Name").getValue().toString();
                                String address = snapshot.child("Address").getValue().toString();
                                String timing = snapshot.child("Timing").getValue().toString();
                                String about = snapshot.child("About").getValue().toString();
          Name.setText(name);
                                Address.setText(address);
                                Timing.setText(timing);
                                About.setText(about);
        } }
              @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onCancelled: DatabaseError Bossu");
                        }
                    });
                }
        
        
            }
        }

    Activity:
      Intent intent = new Intent(GamecenterActivity.this, Center_details.class);
                        intent.putExtra("User",position);
                        startActivity(intent);

Error:
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()
```

Thank you!!.................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you get null value through intent
here is the issue

```
UsersId  = getIntent().getStringExtra("User");

if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(UsersId))
```

then call firebase

Comment: Why am I getting null? Now it isn't getting crash but nothing appearing. I used if at first to check usersid right? So now what should I do?

Comment: if your user id not null then call the firebase function to get data otherwise simply show toast user id equal to null if you want to check how we resolve user id null issue then check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66091758/android-studio-getintent-getstringextra-returns-null/66095995#66095995

Comment: Bro In this time also it is showing null even after I used your code

Comment: That Intent.EXTRA_TEXT

Comment: See my edited code, Help me to solve this issue

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(centerActivity.this, Center_details.class);
                        intent.putExtra("User",position);
                        startActivity(intent);  replace this in Center Activity

Comment: if (getIntent().hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: Checking for input");  first remove this check on Center_details class

Comment: then change this line       UsersId  = getIntent().getStringExtra("User");

Comment: Still it shows null in UsersId, why? how to solve?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228520/discussion-between-muhammad-aslam-and-madhanmohan).